# How to add jquery lower version for a particular drupal page?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have installed the jQuery Update module and set jQuery 1.10 as default jQuery version, but one of my previous functionality stop working.

I just want to use jQuery 1.8 for a specific page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://needsmorejquery.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your condition to remove jquery 1.10 :

```
function THEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
if ($your_condition) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_update') . '/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js';
    unset($javascript[$path]);
    drupal_add_js('path/to/jquery1.8');
}
```

Comment: I have placed the theme_js_alter in my custom module, but its not working.
Where should I keep this function?

Comment: @Ann You need to replace 'THEME' with the name of your theme.  See also https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7.x

Answer (score 4):

You can use `hook_js_alter` to add, remove JS files and change the source of existing JS files.

Something like this should work:

```
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if (arg(0) == 'special-page') {
    javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js';
  }
}
```